# HTML Excel Link Can't Find File?

Tags: html, excel

I'm using this string before a pathway to a local excel document:

`ms-excel:ofe|u|`

The filepath looks like something like this "Y:/My Files/Organization/This Folder/

When clicking on the rendered link, Excel launches but I get the "Sorry, can't find file" alert which displays the failed path, wherein each space and back-slash are replaced with `%20`

Am I using that aforementioned ms-excel string correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ms-excel:ofe|u|file:///${batchPath}
```

The missing bit was `file:///` along that string. With that, the locally saved filepaths launched without issue!